# Benchmark.measure don't give me User, System and Total time

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

For a training case, I have to use Benchmark.measure to evaluate the performances of 2 methods, and I need the Total time to validate a Rspec.
But on my computer, Benchmark.measure just returns me the real time, the other values are 0.

When I execute this piece of code :

```
b1 = Benchmark.measure { find_book(BOOKS_1000, BOOKS_1000.last) }
puts "B1 - #{b1}"

b2 = Benchmark.measure { find_book_enhanced(BOOKS_1000, BOOKS_1000.last) }
puts "B2 - #{b2}
```

I have these results :

```
B1 -   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000167)
B2 -   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000023)
```

I have the same missing values when I test it in irb :

```
[13] pry(main)> Benchmark.measure { "a"*1_000_000 }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fffd6273750
 @cstime=0.0,
 @cutime=0.0,
 @label="",
 @real=0.0027145999999902415,
 @stime=0.0,
 @total=0.0,
 @utime=0.0>
```

If I use Process.times, I have a full set of data :

```
[14] pry(main)> t = Process.times
=> #<struct Process::Tms
 utime=0.546875,
 stime=1.078125,
 cutime=0.03125,
 cstime=0.171875>
```

I don't understand why I have this issue, I'm the only one whit the result (on 17 students), and my teachers don't understand it too, they never met it before me.

My computer is up-to-date (OS Win10 Home and drivers).

I can change the Rspec to validate my code then forget this problem, but I'm curious to know the origin of this issue.
Anyone can help me to understand it ?